# After importing Excel file to MySQl, Date is showing as 0000-00-00

Tags: mysql, date

I tried by changing the format in excel to yyyy-mm-dd. After changing the format the problem still exists. What is the solution?

Comment: You are importing right into phpmyadmin, right? I guess the raw-values are getting imported, not the formated-values.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is: Open your excel-doc and change the format of every cell to text(string). I guess you'll have to change the shown values manually to an other format. Save it then and import again. Should import the correct way.

If the problem persists, please tell how you are importing the doc into ur db.